# Gerar valor aleatório unico com php

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, random

Preciso gerar um valor aleatório com letras e números no PHP, sempre iniciando-se com a letra A e tendo números e letras misturados ao valor. É referente ao campo "código de controle" contido neste script:

```
    <?php require("header.php");?>
<?php require("menu.php");

if(isset($_POST['bt_save_df']))
{
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$arquivo = $_POST['arquivo'];
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$codcontrol = $_POST['codcontrol'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$material = $_POST['material'];
$denominacao = $_POST['denominacao'];

$uploaddir = 'desenhos/arquivos/';
$pastadestino = 'desenhos/arquivos/';
// Pega a extensão do arquivo
$dividir2 = end(explode(".", $_FILES['imagem1']['name']));

// Gera um nome aleatório
$nome = time();
$nome_imagem2 = $nome . '1.' . $dividir2;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $nome . '1.' . $dividir2;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem1']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $nome_imagem2)) {

}

$arquivo = $pastadestino.$nome_imagem2;


$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_desenho (nome, arquivo, codigo, codcontrol, tipo, material, denominacao)';
$sql .= ' VALUES (:nome, :arquivo, :codigo, :codcontrol, :tipo, :material, :denominacao)';

try{

    $create = $db->prepare($sql);
    $create->bindValue(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $create->bindValue(':arquivo', $arquivo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $create->bindValue(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $create->bindValue(':codcontrol', $codcontrol, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $create->bindValue(':tipo', $tipo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $create->bindValue(':material', $material, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $create->bindValue(':denominacao', $denominacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($create->execute() ){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" >
                alert( "Registro Cadastrado com Sucesso!"); location.href="ger_arquivos.php";
        </script>';

    }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro ao Cadastrar Registro! - " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>


            <!-- BEGIN Main Content -->
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-title">
                            <h3><i class="icon-reorder"></i> Cadastro de Desenhos</h3>
                            <div class="box-tool">
                                <a data-action="collapse" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                <a data-action="close" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-content">
                            <form action="cad_arquivo.php" class="form-horizontal" id="validation-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="nome">Titulo:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="input-xlarge" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="titulo">Código:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" class="input-xlarge" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="titulo">Código de Controle:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <input type="text" name="codcontrol" id="codcontrol" class="input-xlarge" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="select">Tipo:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
                                                <option value=""> -- Selecione --</option>
                                                <option value="1">Produção</option>
                                                <option value="2">Kits</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="titulo">Material:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <input type="text" name="material" id="material" class="input-xlarge" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="titulo">Denominação:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <input type="text" name="denominacao" id="denominacao" class="input-xlarge" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="control-group">
                                  <label class="control-label">Arquivo</label>
                                  <div class="controls">
                                     <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                        <div class="input-append">
                                           <div class="uneditable-input">
                                              <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i> 
                                              <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                                           </div>
                                           <span class="btn btn-file">
                                               <span class="fileupload-new">Selecione o arquivo</span>
                                               <span class="fileupload-exists">Alterar</span>
                                               <input type="file" class="default" name="imagem1" id="imagem1"/>
                                           </span>
                                           <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>



                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="bt_save_df" value="Salvar">
                                    <a href="ger_arquivos.php"><button type="button" class="btn">Voltar</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Main Content -->
```

Deve ser gerado automaticamente, pois irei eliminar a parte "código de controle" dessa opção.

No caso, a variável codcontrol deve ser suprida automaticamente com essas regras, como eu poderia fazer, eliminando totalmente este input?

Comment: Qual é a estrutura do código de controle? Qual é o tamanho máximo e mínimo? Tens acesso ao sistema de ficheiros? O código está a ser executado em Linux? Tens acesso às bibliotecas SSL? É necessário que o código de controle seja criptograficamente seguro? Estes dados são importantes para poder dar uma resposta acertiva.

Comment: Não há necessário segurança, é só um valor de identificação. Até 9 dígitos é o suficiente, o servidor é em linux. O tamanho minimo pode ser 2. Não tenho acesso as bibliotecas SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira diferente é dividir a lista de caracteres e utilizar um monte de `str_shuffle`.

Eis um exemplo:

```
$id = 'A'.substr(
    str_shuffle(
        str_shuffle('ghijkl').
        str_shuffle(6543).
        str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHI').
        str_shuffle('012').
        str_shuffle('fedcba').
        str_shuffle('ZYXWVUTSRQ').
        str_shuffle('mnopqr').
        str_shuffle(789).
        str_shuffle('JKLMNOP').
        str_shuffle('zyxwvuts')
    ),

    mt_rand(0,53),
    mt_rand(2,9)
);
```

A variável `$id` irá ter uma chave *random* de tamanho *random* das strings arranjadas de maneira *random*.

As strings utilizadas podem ser alteradas da maneira que for preferível.

Comment: Bom se ele não precisar de IDs únicas pois tem o mesmo problema da outra resposta ele pode gerar mais de uma vez o mesmo ID http://ideone.com/k3Vz5J

Comment: @AdirKuhn Podes ler este comentário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59779/gerar-valor-aleat%c3%b3rio-unico-com-php/59821?noredirect=1#comment123248_59779 Além disso, é bastante trivial verificar se uma chave já existe. E esses são os resultados para a distribuição de valores com base nestas strings definidas por mim. Elas podem ser alteradas a gosto. Se tivesse acesso ao sistema de ficheros, faria melhor.

Comment: ou evitar toda essas linhas de código por uma função nativa do PHP que garante ID único (uniqid) como está no título da pergunta, sem ter que fazer consulta extra em banco de dados para ver se a chave já existe.

Comment: @AdirKuhn Tal como está no comentário: `"Não tenho acesso as bibliotecas SSL."`

Comment: SSL? Cara você leu? Deixa eu citar o manual do php aqui "There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core." Ou seja, faz parte do core não precisa instalar nada ou ter SSL.

Comment: @AdirKuhn Então não existe `"uma função nativa do PHP que garante ID único"`. Lê http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php para veres do que falo.

Comment: http://php.net/uniqid função nativa do PHP que garante ID único nessa aplicação pois está apenas num servidor (ele não garante unicidade global pois é gerada com base em milionésimos de segundo e pode acontecer de servidores distintos gerarem o mesmo código). Mas como disse nesse caso sempre será único. Mas ok você venceu

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
<?php

function id_unico() {

    return uniqid("A"); 
}
```

Mais informação sobre o uniqid http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php

Exemplo: http://ideone.com/GLfKLp

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar uma funcao como essa:

```
function valorAleatorio($qtdSorteio = 5) {
    $letras = array('A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','X'); // precisa ter 9 itens
    $resultado = '';
    while($qtdSorteio > 0) {
        $resultado .= rand(0,9); // sorteia valores entre 0-9
        $resultado .= $letras[$qtdSorteio]; // retorna do array a letra pela chave
        $qtdSorteio--;
    }

    return 'A'.$resultado;
}
```

Comment: Gostei do seu esquema, mas no caso como eu capturaria esse resultado pra suprir a variável que preciso?

Comment: Esse método gera uma ID mas não garante IDs únicos, como sua formação é aleatória pode ter combinações repetidas. Aqui eu faço o teste de quantas vezes se repete a ID num loop de 10.000 iterações http://ideone.com/869XXG e essa aqui mostrando que com uniqid o ID será realmente unico no mesmo loop de 10.000 interações http://ideone.com/WGeurd